# How to run a zap every X minutes

Tags: zapier

Is there a way to add a timing trigger for zapier to run a flow every X minutes ?

I was using recurrence in power automate and it was pretty easy to configure it, in zapier i find only the Schedule trigger but i can configure it only for each hour

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you can fire off a webhook using a simple script & cron job, you could have Zapier catch the hook and use that as your trigger.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of Zapier because people don't have cron jobs?